# Kickstart using only SAN disks

Tags: rhel, kickstart

How would a kickstart file look like (using RHEL or a RHEL derivative), or is it even possible with it when we have zero local disks, and we only have disks from SAN? (Kickstart method is needed because of automated installs.)

Comment: What are the paths to these SAN disks?

Answer (score 0):

If you want kickstart to only use the remote disks then you could do this:

```
install --firstdisk=remote
```